# NoClassDefFoundError: WordCount with hadoop-2.2.0 on ubuntu-12.04

Tags: java, hadoop

I executed wordcount program hadoop-2.2.0 in ubuntu-12.04 desktop and getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: WordCount (wrong name: org/myorg/WordCount)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:205)
```

Comment: Really lacking information to answer. What command did you execute?

Answer (score -1):

I guess that you didn't run your wordcount class correctly

`NoClassDefFoundError` : This exception indicates that the JVM looked in its internal class definition data structure for the definition of a class and did not find it. This is different than saying that it could not be loaded from the classpath. Usually this indicates that we previously attempted to load a class from the classpath, but it failed for some reason - now we're trying to use the class again (and thus need to load it, since it failed last time), but we're not even going to try to load it, because we failed loading it earlier (and reasonably suspect that we would fail again). The earlier failure could be a ClassNotFoundException or an ExceptionInInitializerError (indicating a failure in the static initialization block) or any number of other problems. The point is, a NoClassDefFoundError is not necessarily a classpath problem.

please follow this [link](http://portal.futuregrid.org/manual/hadoop-wordcount) it explains you how to run a MapReduce program correctly